# Combain arrays with array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have these type four separate arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmbt
    [1] => cmbt
)
Array
(
    [0] => airport
    [1] => guindy
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 500
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2500
    [1] => 1000
)
```

and I need to combine as a result like this

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'cmbt',
        'airport',
        1000,
        2500
    ),
    1 => array(
        'cmbt',
        'guindy',
        500,
        1000,
    )
```

Please help me...

Comment: Did you tried any thing.At least you could do it using loop.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your main array is $all_array:

```
$wanted_array = array(0 => array(), 1 => array());
foreach($all_array as $element)
{
    $wanted_array[0][] = $element[0];
    $wanted_array[1][] = $element[1];
}
```

To say this doesn't contain any error handling if any malformed `$all_array` is happening. But it should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
$final_array = [];

$final_array[] = array_column($your_array, 0); 

$final_array[] = array_column($your_array, 1);
```

`$your_array` in this context assumes that there's a big array containing all 4 of your smaller arrays. That should be a problem overall.

It should get you started on a good track.

Answer (score 1):

SPL's [MultipleIterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) are very useful for this type of task:

```
$array1 = [
    'cmbt', 'cmbt',
];
$array2 = [
    'airport', 'guindy',
];
$array3 = [
    1000, 500,
];
$array4 = [
    2500, 1000,
];


$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array3));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array4));
$result = [];
foreach($mi as $values) {
    $result[] = $values;
}

var_dump($result);
```